# Orbeon, Form Builder - validate fields via web service

Tags: orbeon, xforms

Is it possible to validate some fields via web service? For example when I push a button 'validate this section' and connect results from web service with standard orbeon validator ?  My temporary solution is to add some output field with styles="position:fixed" and display some informations from my web service validator in it.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, it's not directly possible, and you have to resort to a workaround like the one you're describing. There is a request for enhancement for this, see [issue #1304](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1304).